# Two methods within a runBlocking coroutine. Second doesn't wait for the first

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the problem that my `saveStore` function doesn't wait for the `uploadImagesFunction` function. The last one loops through an array of multiple images and loads each into [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start?hl=de). The `saveStore` function should only be called when all images have been processed. For this i use the `runBlocking` coroutine. The problem is that `saveStore` is always called immediately without waiting for the first Method to finish. What do I have to change?

```
binding.save.setOnClickListener {

 runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
   uploadImagesFunction()
   saveStore()

  }

}


...

 private fun uploadImagesFunction(){

    val storeImageRef = storageRef.child("/storeImages/${UUID.randomUUID()}.jpg")

     uploadImages.forEach { element ->
        var file = element
        val uploadTask = storeImageRef.putFile(file)
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {
         //Error
           ...
        }.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
          //Success - go on
         
        }

    }
}

private fun saveStore(){

    val store = hashMapOf(
        "name" to  binding.storeName.editableText.toString(),
        ...
    )

    db.collection("stores").add(store).addOnSuccessListener {document->

    ... }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `suspend` functions here, so you're not really using coroutines. Your functions are regular functions that use another asynchronous mechanism (based on callbacks).

If you really want to use coroutines, you should make these async calls suspend instead of using callbacks.

If you're using Firebase, you can probably leverage the [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services) library, and use the [Task.await()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/await.html) or [Task.asDeferred()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/as-deferred.html) functions for this purpose instead of using `addOnSuccessListener` and the likes.

For instance:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.asDeferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await

binding.save.setOnClickListener {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        uploadImagesFunction()
        saveStore()
    }
}


private suspend fun uploadImagesFunction() {
    val storeImageRef = storageRef.child("/storeImages/${UUID.randomUUID()}.jpg")
    uploadImages
        .map { file -> storeImageRef.putFile(file).asDeferred() } 
        .awaitAll()
}

private suspend fun saveStore() {
    val store = hashMapOf(
        "name" to  binding.storeName.editableText.toString(),
        ...
    )

    db.collection("stores").add(store).await()
}
```

Note that you are assigning the same UUID for every image here, which is probably not what you want. You should probably instead generate a new UUID for each item in the list (just move the `storageRed.child(...)` call into the `map`).

Comment: If i try to add suspend i got the message Redundant 'suspend' modifier

Comment: @Captai-N I meant really turning the function into a suspending function by changing the callback approach to coroutine-based one, not just adding the `suspend` modifier. Did you try adding the dependency I mentioned and call `await()` on your task instead of using callbacks?

Comment: @Captai-N I edited the answer to show you what I mean

Answer (score 0):

`runBlocking` is not recommended because it can lead to an unresponsive ui. You should leverage asynchronous programming using coroutines.

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            uploadImagesFunction(
                onComplete = {
                    saveStore()
                }
            )
        }

private suspend fun uploadImagesFunction(onComplete: () -> Unit) {
    val storeImageRef = storageRef.child("/storeImages/${UUID.randomUUID()}.jpg")
    uploadImages.forEach { element ->
        var file = element
        storeImageRef.putFile(file).await()
    }
    onComplete()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed it like this. Unfortunately without success. saveStore is called immediately. If I set breakpoints in both methods, saveStore is finished long before the uploadImagesFunction in the addOnSuccessListener method has arrived with the first image

Comment: If you try this in an empty application you will see that it actually waits. Since the problem may be caused by firebase `async task`, I added a new method for you to try.

Comment: Why do you need `launch` at all here? You're not actually using coroutines, you're using callbacks.

Comment: `storeImageRef.putFile(file).await()`
await() in this code
it is the `kotlinx.coroutines.tasks` function. `onComplete` runs only when the operation is completed.

Comment: And if you don't use `await()` in a scope, as you know you will see an error like this. _suspend function await() should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function_

Comment: `uploadImagesFunction` in your code is not suspending so I stopped there. If you're using `await()` from a library you should mention it in your answer, I think you're talking about the same `await()` as I do in my answer, and in that case your function will not compile if it's not `suspend`. It is indeed possible to turn it into a suspending function, but then you don't want this callback after every insertion, you want to use suspend functions in sequence, that's the whole point.

Comment: By `await()` we mean the same thing and yes you are right. The function must already be a `suspend` function. I missed adding this part. And yes `onComplete` should not be triggered on every for. We don't want that either. Totally agree. I edited the answer.